# Changing to a link in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I have searched around and gave an honest effort for the last few days (all day) and I can't seem to get it right so I put it back to at least be able to show the CLICK HERE in the wheel. For example, the CLICK HERE could get to peredy1.com, etc. I tried all the examples I could find with no luck (a.href, a href=" ", etc)

What I need to do, is when the wheel stops it shows a clickable link for that winning selection. I did not write this but I customized it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the section in question

```
var data = [
    {"label":"2 Songs",  "value":1,  "question":"<a href="https://www.peredy1.com">CLICK HERE</a>"}, // padding
    {"label":"1 Song",  "value":1,  "question":"CLICK HERE"}, //font-family
    {"label":"2 Songs",  "value":1,  "question":"CLICK HERE"}, //color
    {"label":"1 Song",  "value":1,  "question":"CLICK HERE"}, //font-weight
    {"label":"1 Song",  "value":1,  "question":"CLICK HERE"}, //font-size
    {"label":"1 Song",  "value":1,  "question":"CLICK HERE"}, //background-color
    {"label":"3 Songs",  "value":1,  "question":"CLICK HERE"}, //nesting
    {"label":"1 Song",  "value":1,  "question":"CLICK HERE"}, //bottom
    {"label":"2 Songs",  "value":1,  "question":"CLICK HERE"}, //sans-serif
    {"label":"1 Song", "value":1, "question":"CLICK HERE"} //period         
];
```

Here is the whole page...

```js
var padding = {
    top: 20,
    right: 40,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0
  },
  w = 500 - padding.left - padding.right,
  h = 500 - padding.top - padding.bottom,
  r = Math.min(w, h) / 2,
  rotation = 3,
  oldrotation = 0,
  picked = 100000,
  oldpick = [],
  color = d3.scale.category20();

var data = [{
      "label": "2 Songs",
      "value": 1,
      "question": "<a href="
      https: //www.peredy1.com">CLICK HERE</a>"}, // padding
      {
        "label": "1 Song",
        "value": 1,
        "question": "CLICK HERE"
      }, //font-family
      {
        "label": "2 Songs",
        "value": 1,
        "question": "CLICK HERE"
      }, //color
      {
        "label": "1 Song",
        "value": 1,
        "question": "CLICK HERE"
      }, //font-weight
      {
        "label": "1 Song",
        "value": 1,
        "question": "CLICK HERE"
      }, //font-size
      {
        "label": "1 Song",
        "value": 1,
        "question": "CLICK HERE"
      }, //background-color
      {
        "label": "3 Songs",
        "value": 1,
        "question": "CLICK HERE"
      }, //nesting
      {
        "label": "1 Song",
        "value": 1,
        "question": "CLICK HERE"
      }, //bottom
      {
        "label": "2 Songs",
        "value": 1,
        "question": "CLICK HERE"
      }, //sans-serif
      {
        "label": "1 Song",
        "value": 1,
        "question": "CLICK HERE"
      } //period

    ];


    var svg = d3.select('#chart')
      .append("svg")
      .data([data])
      .attr("width", w + padding.left + padding.right)
      .attr("height", h + padding.top + padding.bottom);

    var container = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "chartholder")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + (w / 2 + padding.left) + "," + (h / 2 + padding.top) + ")");

    var vis = container
      .append("g");

    var pie = d3.layout.pie().sort(null).value(function(d) {
      return 1;
    });

    // declare an arc generator function
    var arc = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(r);

    // select paths, use arc generator to draw
    var arcs = vis.selectAll("g.slice")
      .data(pie)
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .attr("class", "slice");


    arcs.append("path")
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
      return color(i);
    })
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      return arc(d);
    });

    // add the text
    arcs.append("text").attr("transform", function(d) {
      d.innerRadius = 0;
      d.outerRadius = r;
      d.angle = (d.startAngle + d.endAngle) / 2;
      return "rotate(" + (d.angle * 180 / Math.PI - 90) + ")translate(" + (d.outerRadius - 10) + ")";
    })
    .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .text(function(d, i) {
      return data[i].label;
    });

    container.on("click", spin);


    function spin(d) {

      container.on("click", null);

      //all slices have been seen, all done
      console.log("OldPick: " + oldpick.length, "Data length: " + data.length);
      if (oldpick.length == data.length) {
        console.log("done");
        container.on("click", null);
        return;
      }

      var ps = 360 / data.length,
        pieslice = Math.round(1440 / data.length),
        rng = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1440) + 360);

      rotation = (Math.round(rng / ps) * ps);

      picked = Math.round(data.length - (rotation % 360) / ps);
      picked = picked >= data.length ? (picked % data.length) : picked;


      if (oldpick.indexOf(picked) !== -1) {
        d3.select(this).call(spin);
        return;
      } else {
        oldpick.push(picked);
      }

      rotation += 90 - Math.round(ps / 2);

      vis.transition()
        .duration(3000)
        .attrTween("transform", rotTween)
        .each("end", function() {

          //mark question as seen
          d3.select(".slice:nth-child(" + (picked + 1) + ") path")
            .attr("fill", "#111");

          //populate question
          d3.select("#question h1")
            .text(data[picked].question);

          oldrotation = rotation;

          container.on("click", spin);
        });
    }

    //make arrow
    svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (w + padding.left + padding.right) + "," + ((h / 2) + padding.top) + ")")
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", "M-" + (r * .15) + ",0L0," + (r * .05) + "L0,-" + (r * .05) + "Z")
    .style({
      "fill": "black"
    });

    //draw spin circle
    container.append("circle")
    .attr("cx", 0)
    .attr("cy", 0)
    .attr("r", 60)
    .style({
      "fill": "white",
      "cursor": "pointer"
    });

    //spin text
    container.append("text")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 15)
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text("SPIN")
    .style({
      "font-weight": "bold",
      "font-size": "30px"
    });


    function rotTween(to) {
      var i = d3.interpolate(oldrotation % 360, rotation);
      return function(t) {
        return "rotate(" + i(t) + ")";
      };
    }


    function getRandomNumbers() {
      var array = new Uint16Array(1000);
      var scale = d3.scale.linear().range([360, 1440]).domain([0, 100000]);

      if (window.hasOwnProperty("crypto") && typeof window.crypto.getRandomValues === "function") {
        window.crypto.getRandomValues(array);
        console.log("works");
      } else {
        //no support for crypto, get crappy random numbers
        for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
          array[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000) + 1;
        }
      }

      return array;
    }
```

```css
text {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 39px;
  font-weight: bold;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#chart {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#question {
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
  top: 0;
  left: 520px;
  padding: 5;
  margin: 5;
}

#question h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="chart"></div>
<div id="question">
  <h1></h1>
</div>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: It would be better if your example is shorter. e.g. the code where you try to change the link itself.

Comment: Okay sorry, I will remember that. I thought maybe the rest of it would be needed to make it work. My apologies.

Comment: I made a section for that to show by itself. Thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution for you. You made an error writing the variable `data`:

```
var data = [
  {"label":"2 Songs",  "value":1,  "question":"<a href="https://www.peredy1.com">CLICK HERE</a>"}, // padding
  {"label":"1 Song",  "value":1,  "question":"CLICK HERE"}, //font-family
  {"label":"2 Songs",  "value":1,  "question":"CLICK HERE"}, //color
  {"label":"1 Song",  "value":1,  "question":"CLICK HERE"}, //font-weight
  {"label":"1 Song",  "value":1,  "question":"CLICK HERE"}, //font-size
  {"label":"1 Song",  "value":1,  "question":"CLICK HERE"}, //background-color
  {"label":"3 Songs",  "value":1,  "question":"CLICK HERE"}, //nesting
  {"label":"1 Song",  "value":1,  "question":"CLICK HERE"}, //bottom
  {"label":"2 Songs",  "value":1,  "question":"CLICK HERE"}, //sans-serif
  {"label":"1 Song", "value":1, "question":"CLICK HERE"} //period
];
```

on writing question should be `"<a href='https://www.peredy1.com'>CLICK HERE</a>"` do not use double quotes inside double quotes, because it can cause problems. You can use quote one inside quote two.

If you want to html don't use:

```
//populate question
d3.select("#question h1")
    .text(data[picked].question);
```

you should use

```
//populate question
d3.select("#question h1")
    .html(data[picked].question);
```

Comment: Would you be able to point me in the right direction to limit the amount of times the wheel can be clicked to spin it? I'm not asking for the work to be done for me but I think I don't know what to search for because I'm not finding what I need.